# how to save data from multiple webpages in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

how to save data from multiple webpages in jsp.I have 2 iframes.each of them holds different web pages.I need to save datas from both webpages into database

Comment: OK. So you have a web page, a web server, and a database behind the server. So you need to send an HTTP request from the web page to the web server, containing the data to save, and to make the web server save the sent data to the database. Whether you have one, 2 or 45 web pages doesn't change anything. Each web page needs to do that.

Comment: i have an iframe which holds a webpage with some data to save.it also have another iframe which holds another webpage with data.I need to save the whole data from the multiple webpages into database at once.